# Phusion Passenger can't access mysql

Tags: centos, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I can connect to the db from terminal.

The rails console connects fine also and I can return objects, mod them and do what ever from there. So database.yml must be ok

But for some reason the Passenger just won't connect..

What am I missing?

Error

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be started

There appears to be a database problem.
Your config/database.yml may not be written correctly. Please check it and fix any     errors.
Your database schema may be out of date or nonexistant. Please run rake db:migrate to   ensure that the database schema is up-to-date.
The database server may not be running. Please check whether it's running, and start it    if  it isn't.

Error message:
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)   (Mysql::Error)

Exception class:
Mysql::Error
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of two things:

- The user that passenger is running as doesn't have permission to the socket object,

or,

- The database isn't running.

Since you're able to connect and query from the terminal, it's probably a permission issue.  What user is passenger running as, and what permissions do you get from `ls -l /var/lib/mysql/`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Rails app is actually running in the mode you want it to be running in:

```
grep RAILS_ENV config/environment.rb
grep RailsEnv /path/to/Apache/config
```

and:

```
egrep '^production|^development' -A6 config/database.yml
```